# CN1 simulator openGalery restriction

Tags: codenameone, filechooser

I would like to test the data recovery from zip file.
To select the file I use the example at https://www.codenameone.com/blog/native-file-open-dialogs.html.

During the development it would be convenient to use the simulator for testing. But the openGallery method only handles image, video and audio files.
I'd like to work without an extension filter. I think that introducing a Display.GALLERY_ANY constant and changing the filter setting for the openGalery method may be the solution.

Best regards
Péter

Comment: As a hack for testing you can just rename the file to .jpg or something as the code inside doesn't really care about the extension it should work fine. Notice you can use `Display.isSimulator()` to create a condition like that in the code for testing only